# Google Play not showing new version of the app unless clear cache of Google Play

Tags: android, caching, google-play, version

I have an app that check the version in-app. If we deploy a new app together with the backend, the app will announce that the user is using the old version of the app, and redirect to google play to update the new released version. Hence they cannot use the app

But the problem occurs when Google Play not showing the latest version unless I clear the cache of google play.

Is there any way I can make google display the new version when redirecting to Google Play (by adding a query flags into the Google Play url or something like that to make Google Play show the latest version?)

Having the users waiting until Google Play show the correct version is not a good practice, as they can't use the app in the mean time. But guiding them to clear google play cache maybe a problem with elderly or non-tech users.

Thank you guys for your time.

Comment: You can use In-app update.

Comment: It's related to the code, like fixing bugs, implementing new features, I don't know if in-app updates can handle this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Android In-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates) it will update the app from within the app without going to Google Play store

[image]

Comment: Oh, so you guys were talking about this in-app update. Gonna take a look. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I've marked this answer the clearest answer. Tried it, but it's not as I expected. It has a huge delay before the update availability is "AVAILABLE" (Google play has already had the update button), I tried updating again after spending the night and it works (Don't know exactly how long before the update became AVAILABLE)

Answer (score -1):

Now the newstips update for android is delayed all together. It was uploading for me day and half ago then when I went to play it was the same old version so I put in a slip and they still haven't explained to me this issue, I had to find out myself on facebook its

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32901152)